# Apply condition to aggregate function result

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to get the amount of days from a table, this is my code (which is working fine):

```
SELECT
    person,
    sum(((until - since) + 1)) as days
FROM 
    periods
GROUP BY person;
```

Now I want to add a condition to keep only the ones with 365 days or more so I wrote this code but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT
    person,
    sum(((until - since) + 1)) as days
FROM 
    periods
GROUP BY person
HAVING days = 365;
```

**EDIT**: The error: column "days" does not exist

Comment: "*doesn't work*" isn't a valid Postgres error message. Please post the **exact** error message you get.

Comment: Try: `HAVING sum(((until - since) + 1)) = 365`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use "HAVING" if you're naming columns with "AS". Try this;

```
SELECT
    person,
    sum(((until - since) + 1)) as days
FROM 
    periods
GROUP BY person
HAVING sum(((until - since) + 1)) = 365;
```

Comment: You left out the "HAVING". (See kordirko's answer.)